# Ajax function not called when included

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have an ajax function that is not run when the ajax script is included in my HTML page like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='ajax.js'></script>
```

However, if I place the exact same script in the **head** portion of the HTML page, then it does run.

Why does this occur, and how can I fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function() {

            $(".a").click(function() 
            {    
                  $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "1.php",
                     data: dataString,
                     cache: false,
                     success: function(html)
                       {
                           //stuff
                       }  
                   });

                return false;
            });

        });

</script>
```

Comment: You mean it is included via Ajax? If not, why don't you put it in the head?

Comment: the above ajax script is called in the HTML page like i stated above.  it won't work that way.  it only works if placed directly in the head.  why?

Comment: @Sev - Is the script (as an external file) being included **after** jquery, or before?

Comment: @Sev - You sure there aren't any javascript errors occurring?

Comment: It might be that the `ajax.js` script is not in the same directory as your HTML page.

Test what happens if you type in the full URL to `ajax.js` in your browser. If, for example, the HTML page that you wrote is located at `http://localhost/index.html`, then what do you see at `http://localhost/ajax.js`?

Comment: @Daniel, checked the path, it's correct.  @Nick, well I didn't check with any error checker, but I know I copied the EXACT same script into the Head section and it worked properly.

Comment: @Sev - If there are any errors, it may stop the JS thread, see if your firebug or chrome console shows any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might seem trivial but did you remove the `<script>` tags when using it in an external `.js` file?

The contents of your `ajax.js` file should *just* be:

```
$(function() {
  $(".a").click(function() {    
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "1.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html)
      {
        //stuff
      }  
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

I have the impression that when you mentioned "*exactly*", you left the script tags intact in the `ajax.js` file.

Also if this still doesn't work. try added an `alert("hello");` line at the top of `ajax.js` before everything to see whether it runs *at all*.

Comment: hehe, dumb mistake on my part, but you caught it!  good job :)

Comment: No problem. Happy scripting! :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a example which worked fine for me. cant see any problems so im guessing its a mistype or something silly.

here is the sample code i used:

HTML:
    //double check these paths

```
<body>
<a class="a" href="#">clicky</a>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
// i noticed you put .a here instead of a, i am assuming you are referring the class
$(".a").click(function() 
{    
    alert("1");
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "1.php",
         data: "html",
         cache: false,
         success: function(data)
           {
         //stuff
         $("body").html(data);
           }  
       });

    return false;
});
```

});

PHP:

```
echo 'bar';
```

Comment: and you included the javascript using something like this: <script type='text/javascript' src='ajax.js'></script> ?

Comment: yep  this is the exact html i put in my file:

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript' src='ajax.js'></script>